# Low Quality Review Queue - Resolve by marking it Spam

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, spam, low-quality-posts

I recently [learned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226841/who-picks-audit-questions) that the review queue for low quality posts includes audits from those posts flagged as spam.

Just today I came across a post in said queue that actually looked like spam. A very short answer with a link to a commercial product that did not answer the OPs question.

So I clicked on "Recommend Deletion", and... there is no way to give "Spam" as the reason. The best option I could find was "No comment needed". All other reasons would have been plain wrong.

So I suggest either *removing the "Spam" audits from the queue*, OR giving the *option to recommand deletion as "Spam"*.

It's somewhat sadistic to audit for Spam, without providing a good way to actually handle spam. I know the audits only check if you clicked on "recommand deletion", but anyway... if you *want* me to identify Spam, *let* me identify Spam.

Comment: I'm going to look into the actual mechanics that make having the flag link there technically difficult (I believe it does have something to do with audits) - this keeps coming up.

Comment: You could click on the title of the question to open the actual question, then flag the spam from there.